# MYSQL How to select a row where a field is minimum inside another select

Tags: mysql

I have a table `ab_ws_zpt` with the columns: `WS_ID`, `ZPT_ID`, `abstand`.

[Data of "ab_ws_zpt"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTfkI.jpg) This is just a short abstract from the entire data. `WS_ID` goes up to 43 and entirely there are 600.000 `ZPT_ID´s`.

I try to select the `WS_ID` from the row with the minimum abstand in a specific select of a `ZPT_ID`.

It works when I just select the minimum abstand from the entire table `ab_ws_zpt` with:

```
SELECT 
    WS_ID, ZPT_ID, abstand
FROM
    ab_ws_zpt
WHERE
    abstand = (SELECT MIN(abstand) from ab_ws_zpt);`
```

which brings the result of: [Result of select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ov4.jpg)

Also it works when I just select all `WS_ID`´s of one special `ZPT_ID` with:

```
SELECT 
    WS_ID, ZPT_ID, abstand
FROM
    ab_ws_zpt 
WHERE
    ZPT_ID = '70000003';
```

Which results all 43 `WS_ID` for the `ZPT_ID` 70000003.

Now I tried to  combine both statements into:

```
SELECT 
    WS_ID, ZPT_ID, abstand
FROM
    ab_ws_zpt
WHERE
    abstand = (SELECT 
            MIN(abstand)
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                WS_ID, b.ZPT_ID, abstand
            FROM
                ab_ws_zpt 
            WHERE
                ZPT_ID = '70000003'));
```

And the database returns the `errorcode 1248`: Every derived table must have its own alias.

I tried to give the tables different alias in both selects, but the error keeps resulting. I hope someone can help me and correct my error or show me another way to get what i want.

This is my first question on here, so I´m sorry if my explanations are missleading. I tried my best to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Have you tried getting only `abstand`s inside your inner `select` like :`SELECT abstand  FROM ab_ws_zpt WHERE ZPT_ID = '70000003'` ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    WS_ID, ZPT_ID, abstand
FROM
    ab_ws_zpt
WHERE
ZPT_ID = '70000003'
ORDER BY abstand ASC
LIMIT 1;
```